# PHP,JavaScript を使ったフォームが送信できない

Tags: javascript, php, form

PHP,JavaScript初心者です。送信ボタンを押してもJavaScriptで設定した「メール送信に失敗しました」アラートが出ます。
本番サーバーにあげてチェックしています。（ConoHa）
原因はどこにあるのでしょうか？

#### htmlのフォーム部分

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
  <form id="mailform">
    <div>
      <label for="nameval">名前<span>(必須)</span></label> <input type="text" name="nameval" id="nameval" required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="mailval">メールアドレス<span>(必須)</span></label> <input type="email" name="mailval" id="mailval" required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="urlval">ウェブサイト</label> <input type="text" name="urlval" id="urlval" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="textval">内容<span>(必須)</span></label> <textarea name="textval" id="textval" rows="12" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <p class="contact-submit">
      <input type="submit" value="送信 »" id="submit"> <input
      id="referrer" type="hidden" name="referrer" />
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="dispmsg"></div>
```

#### sendmail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

$to = 'aaaa@aaaaa.com';
$subject = 'お問い合わせフォームより';
$domain = 'aaaaa.com';

$errflg =0;
$dispmsg ='';

$nameval = '';
$mailval = '';
$urlval = '';
$textval = '';
$referrer = '';

if(isset($_POST['nameval'])){ $nameval = $_POST['nameval']; }
if(isset($_POST['mailval'])){ $mailval = $_POST['mailval']; }
if(isset($_POST['urlval'])){ $urlval = $_POST['urlval']; }
if(isset($_POST['textval'])){ $textval = $_POST['textval']; }
if(isset($_POST['referrer'])){ $referrer = $_POST['referrer']; }

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $domain) === false){
  $dispmsg = '<p id="errmsg">【リファラチェックエラー】お問い合わせフォームから入力されなかったため、メール送信できませんでした。</p>';
  $errflg = 1;
}
else if($nameval == '' || $mailval == '' || $textval == ''){
  $dispmsg = '<p id="errmsg">【エラー】名前・メールアドレス・内容は必須項目です。</p>';
  $errflg = 1;
}
else if(!preg_match("/^[.!#%&-_0-9a-zA-Z?/+]+@[!#%&-_0-9a-z]+(.[!#%&-_0-9a-z]+)+$/", $mailval) || count( explode('@',$mailval) ) !=2){
  $dispmsg .= '<p id="errmsg">【エラー】メールアドレスの形式が正しくありません。</p>';
  $errflg = 1;
}
else{
  $subject = "=?iso-2022-jp?B?".base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($subject,'JIS','UTF-8'))."?=";
  $message= '名前：'.$nameval."\n";
  $message.='メール：'.$mailval."\n";
  $message.='ウェブサイト：'.$urlval."\n";
  $message.="\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――\n\n";
  $message.=$textval;
  $message.="\n\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――\n";
  $message.='送信日時：'.date( "Y/m/d (D) H:i:s", time() )."\n";
  $message.='送信元IPアドレス：'.@$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\n";
  $message.='送信元ホスト名：'.getHostByAddr(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))."\n";
  $message.='リファラURL：'.$referrer."\n";
  $message.='お問い合わせページ：'.@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n";
  $message= mb_convert_encoding($message,'JIS','UTF-8');
  $fromName = mb_encode_mimeheader(mb_convert_encoding($nameval,'JIS','UTF-8'));
  $header ='From: '.$fromName.'<wordpress@'.$domain.'>'."\n";
  $header.='Reply-To: '.$mailval."\n";
  $header.='Content-Type:text/plain;charset=iso-2022-jpnX-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

  $retmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

  if( $retmail ){
    $dispmsg ='<p class="success">メールを送信しました。返信までしばらくお待ちください。</p>';
    $dispmsg.='<blockquote><p>名前： '.hsc_utf8($nameval).'<br />';
    $dispmsg.= 'メール： '.hsc_utf8($mailval).'<br />';
    $dispmsg.= 'ウェブサイト： '.hsc_utf8($urlval).'</p>';
    $dispmsg.= '<pre>'.hsc_utf8($textval).'</pre></blockquote>';
  }else{
    $dispmsg .= '<p id="errmsg">【エラー】メール送信に失敗しました。。</p>';
    $errflg = 1;
  }
}

$result = array('errflg'=>$errflg, 'dispmsg'=>$dispmsg);
echo json_encode( $result );

function hsc_utf8($str) {
  return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
}
?>
```

#### form.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("#referrer").val(document.referrer);
  $("#mailform").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url : '/sendmail.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done( function(data){
      $("#dispmsg").empty();
      $("#dispmsg").html(data.dispmsg);
      if(data.errflg != 1){
        $("#mailform").remove();
      }
    })
    .fail( function(data){
      alert('メール送信に失敗しました');
    })
    return false;
  });
});
```

追記：
ご指摘いただいた部分を修正。これでもまだ動きません。

試したこと：
現状のままフォーム入力し送信ボタンをおす
=> 「メール送信に失敗しました」アラートが出る
sendmail.phpの`$domain = 'aaaaa.com';`を違うアドレスにする
=> 「【リファラチェックエラー】お問い合わせフォームから入力されなかったため、メール送信できませんでした。」は表示される
　==> つまり、PHP,JS共に読み込まれてはいる？

Comment: コードを書き写す際のミスなのかもしれませんが、`sendmail.php` で `$message= '名前：'.$nameval."n";` となっていて、LF(`\n`) が単なる `n` になってますね（`$header`も同様）。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ご指摘部分修正しましたが、まだ動きません。
php,JS共に読み込まれてはいるようなのですが。。。

Comment: 「メール送信に失敗しました」はご自身の設定したエラーメッセージで実際は何らかのエラーが表示されているはずです。[ブラウザの開発ツールでデバッグ](https://qiita.com/KitamuraTakashi/items/9c7aca4ec498e453d1b1)すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: 「ブラウザの開発ツールでデバッグ」する方法教えていただきありがとうございました。
Status Codeは200で正常、他にもこれといった警告などは出ていませんでした。ただ、Form Data として namevalなどは取得できていますが、referrerだけ空欄になっていました。取得できていないということでしょうか？

Comment: .failに入るのはステータスコードがエラーだったりレスポンスが正常でない時の動作です。なんのエラーもないのにfail処理に到達時点で何か重大な見落としがありそうです。

Comment: 修正漏れかと思いますが、`$header.='Content-Type:text/plain;...` の行で `...charset=iso-2022-jpnX-Mailer:...` となっています。

Comment: sendmail.phpのパスは正しですか？ fail が呼び出されのは、phpを呼び出せない または、サーバー処理で致命的なエラーになった時です。

Comment: ＞keitaro_soさん
ありがとうございます。もっと初歩的な見落としがあるのかもしれません。。
＞metropolisさん
すみません、こちらがどのように間違っているのかがわかりませんでした。不勉強で申し訳ないです。。
＞yyzさん
パスはindex.htmlと同じ階層にアップしています。

Comment: @celebhara 現状ですと `Content-Type` と `X-Mailer` が同じ行で繋がっていますので `charset` が不正な値になっています。`$header.='Content-Type:text/plain;charset=iso-2022-jp'."\n";` と `$header.='X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion()."\n";` に変更します。